# Haskell Esqueleto function to compare with a time offset

Tags: haskell, esqueleto

How could I do something similar to this in Esqueleto:

```
DATE_ADD(myDate, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) > otherDate
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want, do you want the Haskell equivalent of this written in Esqueleto, or do you want to know how to write this with the [esqueleto](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-2.4.3) DSL?

Comment: I realised there is no a `DATE_ADD` function. If I will need to implement it myself, any help would be appreciated.